# ideal database field for calling data to

Tags: android

Hello people can someone help.

I have designed a dialog in which I would like to have a field box or some sort that when the dialog is called the TYPE & AMOUNT (link) box's will display the data from database on each item. So for this dialog I have made. The user will click drinks button on the activity before the dialog. And the data will fill theses field boxes once called.

My question is what can I use for this data box caller.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to know how a database table should look like for that data? like component TEXT, type INTEGER, amount REAL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use TextView or EditText widget (depending on if you want user to just see or edit the data respectively) and you can pull data from SQLite Database.

Comment: i think textview is the right way then. can i call the data to anywhere on the layout

Comment: Yes. Just read data from SQLite database to a String variable and use TextView setText method.