# Calling a custom dialog from a database?

Tags: android, database, dialog

Following on from this question:

[ideal database field for calling data to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253748/ideal-database-field-for-calling-data-to)

I have realised that I might be able to simplify my need for information to be brought to the screen by using a Dialog or a Custom Dialog, and by one of these methods I may call the whole finished page from a database instead of using static strings into the layout filling in specific fields with data like I am currently.
There could be a few hundred items or pieces of data to be called up in my App So am I correct with this assumption or do I need a specific other method to acheive this?

I am looking to call a custom dailog from a database so  I can call a whole page of information complete but am unsure of limitations on this data wise or even if my sqlite database manager is even good enough for this task, each page will be called up "complete" where as before I was trying to have a template with the unchanging data (coke pepsi etc.)already included and appearing on every "result" page and then blank fields populated with data retrieved from a sqlite database (Litres size etc...) I am unsure which path to take : either make the page complete including all data like an image Or do I stick with my original plan to have a template screen with unchanging fields already in place and the changing information to be populated as needed from a Sqlite Database? hope this makes sense sorry if I was too vague with my question originally Im still learning.

Comment: I don't think someone understood what you want. `...and by one of these methods I may call the whole finished page from a database...` ?!?!

Comment: I have edited my question above as I cannot explain in a couple of lines on the comments section please read Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is vague but I'll risk an answer:

If you want to make a dialog like the image you posted on your previous question then this is the way to do it:

1. Create a custom dialog that will have as content a `LinearLayout`(with 3 `TextViews` representing the header labels in your image: `COMPONENT`, `TYPE` and `AMOUNT`, this will be somewhat identical to the list row layout below) + a `ListView` where the actual data will be shown.
2. Create a layout file for your `ListView` row to use(like the `LinearLayout` above will contain 3 `TextViews` for the drink name, type number and amount number).
3. When the dialog needs to be shown just get from the database all the drinks names, types and amounts and bind it to the `ListView` with one of the adapters based on a `Cursor`(like a `SimpleCursorAdapter`)

Getting the values from the database and binding them to many `TextViews` is not recommended(If you have many(I saw `few hundred items or pieces of data`)), also your dialog could be called a lot of times by the user in a short period of time and you don't want to do this binding each time for many views.

> either make the page complete including all data like an image

Please don't do this!

Comment: Thank you for you reply i shall looking into 1. just to see how it  looks and feels lets says for the app.